# php How to do a json decode when a child nod is a radom number?

Tags: php, json

here is a json tree from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=japan&prop=categories&format=json

I met a trouble in `"pages": { "15573": {`. If I will turn the query word, the page number is always changed. How to do a json decode when a child nod is a radom number? Thanks.

```
{
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "japan",
                "to": "Japan"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "15573": {
                "pageid": 15573,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Japan",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:All articles containing potentially dated statements"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Article Feedback Pilot"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Articles containing Japanese language text"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Articles containing potentially dated statements from 2010"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Articles containing potentially dated statements from January 2011"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Constitutional monarchies"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Countries bordering the Pacific Ocean"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Countries bordering the Philippine Sea"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:East Asian countries"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 14,
                        "title": "Category:Empires"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "query-continue": {
        "categories": {
            "clcontinue": "15573|Featured articles"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? I've tried and it runs just fine. Do you want to access the random number's value?

Comment: what do you want to get finally? you apply json_decode function and it returns php object and you deal with it. what's exactly you problem?

Comment: @bertzzie, how to do foreach `pages->radom(number)->categories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (based on what you want in comment):

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_array['query']['pages'] as $page)
{
    print_r($page['categories']);
}
```

I'm assuming you want to access it as array, but you can also do it with the default return value, with little modification of course.

Answer (score 1):

After you decode the json, instead of

```
$arr["15573"]
```

access the element with

```
$arr[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the index instead of the array key to acces the value.
example:

```
$array = json_decode( $json_string );
echo $array['query']['pages'][0]['pageid'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is not decoding but accessing that node, because you don't know the value? That could be obtained via

```
$decoded = json_decode( $json, true );
$key     = array_shift( array_keys( $decoded[ 'query' ][ 'pages' ] ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `json_decode($json, true);` to transform that string to array
2. Use array_values to convert keys to indexes starting from 0 :
   `$pages = array_values($jsondecoded["query"]["pages"]);`

Here is the code and output for you: http://codepad.org/3Usm47YZ